# Equilibrium in all directions

Tags: forces, potential-energy, equilibrium

Let's say the origin is an equilibrium position for a particle.
If we have a case such that a slight displacement of the particle in x direction makes it return to the mean position (stable equilibrium) and a slight displacement of the particle in y/z directions makes it go further away from the mean position (unstable equilibrium). The directions of displacement for which particle is in unstable equilibrium are more than directions of displacement for which particle is in stable equilibrium.
I have seen [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362641/situation-of-stable-neutral-and-unstable-equilibrium?rq=1) but the answer didn't clearly state whether there will be an equilibrium type defined for that position or will that position have no type of equilibrium (and the comments on that answer about Unstable equilibrium "winning" over Stable equilibrium confused me even more). So what will we actually call the equilibrium type at the origin? Or will we just define its equilibrium associated with direction (like stable in x direction and such)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a ball balanced on a needle. It is in an unstable equilibrium. It balances if perfectly upright. But if it starts to fall over sideways, it tilts farther out of balance.

Imagine the needle is on a spring. A perfectly balanced ball compresses the spring to a certain height. If the ball is displaced slightly vertically, it returns to the equilibrium height. This is an example of two unstable directions and one stable direction. The unstable direction wins.

Imagine a ball balanced on a knife edge. The knife is curved in the vertical direction into a U shape. A perfectly balanced ball will roll to the bottom of the U. If slightly off balance, it will fall off the knife edge.

Imagine the knife is mounted on a spring. The a perfectly balanced ball at the bottom of the U will return to the equilibrium height. You can imagine more complex behavior for a ball that rolls back and forth along the knife edge as it oscillates up and down. Never the less, it is an unstable equilibrium. A ball slightly off balance will fall.

Comment: Can you provide an image or diagram of the knife curve shape because i cant understand the shape.
Except for that, this was a really clear explanation, Thank you.